# Intellij idea force close - Start failed error

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I'm using Intellij idea the IDE close without any error ! and when I open it again it returns this error:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.MainImpl
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.MainImpl
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:148)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:86)
    ... 1 more
```

How can I resolve this? I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: how do you start the ide?

Comment: Looks like the plugin manager is unable to load a plugin. Did you recently update the IDE? If yes, did you perform plugin updates as well? Ensure that the plugin versions and the IDE versions are compatible. This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970100/intellij-idea-crashes-on-startup-plugin-error

Comment: @ligi with terminal and running` idea.sh`

Comment: @y.feizi what command do you enter in your terminal?

Comment: @harikris ! no only check it for update but dont install it !

Comment: @ligi just enter this line : `'/home/yfeizi/Desktop/idea-IC-135.1230/bin/idea.sh'`

Comment: @y.feizi OK - just wanted to make sure you start via the script - otherwise your classpath is not correct and could produce the above err. I am also using ubuntu and never had this issue

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling and re-installing the IDE. And then start adding one plugin at a time to see which plugin is the culprit. This approach is quick, clean and easy than "trying to fix".

Answer (score 1):

I am using Intellij in Ubuntu too with no errors.
It's hard to say what is happening just by the information provided but I would suggest you to:

1 - Update your Ubuntu with the latest packages

2 - Download the latest version of the IDE, unpack it and try again

Comment: thank you :) i restart my pc and its ok for now ! but i think i must update my Ubuntu